# Is it possible to write a Step without a tasklet in Spring Batch

Tags: spring-batch

I am working on a Spring Batch application where I have written many steps that performs the different actions. However, I want to know if I could write a step without tasklet defined. What could be the purpose of writing that step without tasklet?

Comment: I believe no step without tasklet is there in spring batch

Comment: Out of the box, Spring Batch provides a `Tasklet` based step and a chunk based step.  There is nothing precluding you from implementing the `Step` interface yourself or extending `AbstractStep` and writing your own though.  What is the use case you're attempting to accomplish?